# LAX to Downtown LA

Tags: usa, airport-transfer, los-angeles, lax

I'm going to go from LAX to Downtown LA (let's say Walt Disney Concert Hall for definiteness), and I'm going to take metro since it's cheaper than the flyaway bus. I found some news (https://www.metro.net/projects/green-line-upgrades/lax-transit-options/) saying that the complimentary shuttle (I think it's called route G) will be dropping off passengers at Hawthorne/Lennox Station (as opposed to Aviation/LAX Station). Is this still the case? When I'm returning, should I come to Hawthorne/Lennox Station to take the bus for the airport? (If it's a bad idea to take metro and you think it's worth overpaying for the flyaway bus, let me know, too).

Comment: Just something to point out.  It is INCREDIBLY cheap to rent a car for a day or two, and saves you an enormous amount of hassle.  (Particularly when leaving.  You just .. drive to the airport at your convenience.)  It's just a thought.

Comment: Mind you, I might as well say "If at all possible fly to Burbank instead as it is incredibly more convenient."   :O

Comment: Depending on time of day, a car can get you stuck in severe traffic and parking can be pain too. Ride share (Uber, Lyft) is another option

Comment: I have been in LA during one week driving a RV. The traffic is not so hard comparing with others big cities in US.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will point you to the Metro site for the [Crenshaw/LAX](https://www.metro.net/projects/crenshaw_corridor/) project. At this writing, the Norwalk-bound Green Line will [originate at Crenshaw](https://www.metro.net/projects/notices/Green_Line_Station_Closures_January_2019/) from January 4–20, 2019.

The LAX G shuttle will drop off at the closed Aviation/LAX station as usual. There, go to Bay #8 and board Bus #853, a free temporary shuttle serving all the closed Green Line Stations, and ride it eastbound to Crenshaw.
[image: Map of LA MTA bus 853 service, January 2019]
On the return, similarly, you would take the Green Line to Crenshaw, board the shuttle from the park-and-ride lot (west exit), and transfer to the LAX G shuttle at Aviation/LAX.

---

Nota bene: the FlyAway bus is less than $10 from LAX to downtown. Taking the G shuttle to the Green Line shuttle to the Green Line to the Blue Line adds at least three transfers and at least one change of mode, and to take advantage of the free transfer at Willowbrook–Rosa Parks you need to buy a TAP card ($1 at a vending machine). Moreover, depending on the time of day, you might spend 20 or 30 minutes waiting for buses and trains to arrive, and the Green and Blue Lines don't exactly serve the most picturesque parts of L.A.

I personally wouldn't go through all that to save $7.25, but it's your time and money